# Deploy an Appmaker app to a mobile device or tablet?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to deploy an Appmaker app to a mobile device or tablet? My use case may not have wi-fi access.

The [docs](http://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment) didn't provide any insight as to having downloadable apps on a device.

Comment: Did you try any?

Comment: I read the docs: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment
Didn't provide any insight.

Tried their example apps but they all deploy via a url / browser.

Comment: Okey then! Run the example in your tablet, and you will see if it is responsive or not

Comment: I see where I failed. Let me clarify.

I understand I can run the web browser on a tablet. I'm looking at a scenario where there may not be wi-fi service, so would like to have the Appmaker application run as an app on the device (not in the browser).

Comment: AppMaker does not create mobile apps. It only creates web apps, and they need an internet connection because they check you have a Google account, they access databases which are in the cloud, etc.

Comment: ah, thanks @ValentinCoudert

Answer (score 2):

AppMaker does not create mobile apps. It only creates web apps, and they need an internet connection because they check you have a Google account, they access databases which are in the cloud, etc.

Answer (score 2):

AppMaker may not be the solution to what you are trying to do.

I might suggest FileMaker for offline mobile apps that use a central database/server.